# Language C serial port : read non-canonical mode

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, termios

I'm trying to get data from a STM32 Nucleo Board ( but it doesn't really matter ^^ ).
I want to get raw data and use the non-canonical mode and everything is set up for.
I have set VMIN to 7 to wait until 7 characters are unread and the read wait 7 characters aswell.
However my read returns value before to get 7 values and I don't understand why.
Do you have any idea ? Am I understanding in a wrong way VMIN ?
Thanks for helping me !

My code :

```
int main(){
int r=-1;
char * device = "/dev/ttyS3";
pt = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
if(pt == -1){
    perror("open");
    exit(-1);
}
printf("open : %d\n",pt);
ioctl(pt, I_SRDOPT, RMSGD);
tcgetattr(pt, &old);
atexit(reset_tty);

tcgetattr(pt, &tty); // Get the current attributes of the Serial port

//cfmakeraw(&tty);
tty.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON | IXOFF);
tty.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
tty.c_cflag |= (CS8);
tty.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE|PARENB);
tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ECHONL|ICANON|ISIG|IEXTEN);
tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 7; // wait 7 characters
tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
cfsetispeed(&tty,B9600); // Setting the Baud rate 
cfsetospeed(&tty,B9600);

sleep(1);
r = tcflush(pt, TCIFLUSH);
printf("tcflush : %d\n",r);

r = tcsetattr(pt, TCSANOW, &tty);
printf("tcsetattr : %d\n",r);
int i = 0;
char end[20];

int count = 0;
char line[20];
memset(line,0,sizeof(line));
char forWrite[2]={'A','\0'};

while(count<10){
    r = read(pt ,line,7);
    printf("number of characters : %d\n",r);
    printf("line = %s\n",line);
    //printf("l = %c\n",line[0]);
    count++;
    memset(line,0,sizeof(line));
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

My output :

```
number of characters : 1
line =

number of characters : 2
line = 12

number of characters : 2
line = 33

number of characters : 5
line = 456ab

number of characters : 5
line = cdefg

number of characters : 1
line = a

number of characters : 4
line = bcde

number of characters : 2
line = fg

number of characters : 1
line = 1

number of characters : 3
line = 233
```

And i'm sending from my STM32 "abcdefg" and then "1234567"

EDIT : the code and the output I posted was matching, I have just changed my prints in order to be clearer for you...and I failed ^^, It's edited now thx :)

Comment: Your *"code"* (`printf("read : %d\n",r);` and` printf("l = %s\n",line);`) does not match your *"print"* output (`number of characters : 1` and` line =`).  Nor does the code that you have posted compile without errors and warnings.  You need to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your termios initialization has a bug setting the character size.  The result is that the code you posted would perform I/O with 5-bit characters.  Five bits is insufficient to distinguish between numbers versus letters in ASCII code. Therefore the output you posted could not have been produced by the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry it's edited ^^. A bug ? Can I fix it ? And what do you mean by 5 characters while it seems to have random number of characters read ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what's happening but `read()` (and other I/O interfaces) on "slow" devices (such as serial ports) will return immediately if a signal is received while they are waiting for completion.